# I want to read a file which is present in an artifact(.jar) via AQL without downloading the artifact

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

How can I read the contents of an artifact without downloading it to my local?

I just want to run an AQL which read or gives the specific file content.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Archive Entry Download](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArchiveEntryDownload) we can read/get/download the zipped file let's say MANIFEST.MF file of a jar directly without first downloading the artifact, zipping it, and then finding it.

> http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo1-cache/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar!/META-INF/LICENSE.txt

Mind the: "!" after .jar and before "/META-INF/LICENSE.txt"